# How to add "OTHER" class in Neural Network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have to classify between Real, Fake and Other images but I only have dataset of Real and Fake Faces, how do I add 'other' class, that is neither Real nor Fake face ?

This is how I loaded my dataset

```
TRAINING_DIR = "Dataset\Training Data"
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(TRAINING_DIR,
                                                    batch_size=16,
                                                    target_size=(300, 300))
```

and this is my output

```
Found 1944 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

Comment: If the first two classes are "real" and "fake", then what is "other"?

Comment: 1. Real Face 2. Fake Face 3. Other Object

Comment: Then I do not think that the accepted answer will work. A probability of, say, 50% for an image to be a real face means that the model is unsure. Why not use a collection of images that are not faces as additional training data? Also, _why_ do you need an "other" classification label?

Comment: There is this machine learning competition and they told us to add "other" class. and they didn't provide data, so that's why I was asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Real Face 2. Fake Face 3. Other Object

> There is this machine learning competition and they told us to add "other" class. and they didn't provide data, so that's why I was asking

Does this mean you are not allowed to use any additional data? If you can, take some other images that are not faces. Learn a second, separate model `M2` that has two classes: `FACE` and `OTHER`. For this model, label all of your face images (all real and fake ones together) as `FACE`.

Train your original model `M1` the way you are doing already, with the two classes `REAL` and `FAKE`.

After training those two models, follow a decision process such as this one:

```
For an input image `I`,

Does `M2` predict that the input is a `FACE`?
|--Yes: Does `M1` predict the image is `REAL`?
    |--Yes: Output "real image".
    |--No: Output "fake image".
|--No: Output "other"
```

---

If you cannot use any additional data, try Andrey's answer or look into methods that can detect out-of-distribution inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can predict based on the output of your network. If it predicts the first class with more than 90% probability - then it is the first class. If less then 10% - then it is the second. Otherwise - it is "Other"

Comment: Can you tell me how to get probability of prediction ? In keras ?

Comment: @AdarshWase For multiclasses - your NN output normally has softmax activation (which outputs probabilities). Even if it is not the case - you can apply softmax to your output. I think for binary classification should be something like that